# Why Google Analytics showing very less values?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm running a site since last 10 years. Few months before when I checked total number of countires Since Jan 2011 till date, was 2016 and now it is showing 161.
Same way other figures like total sessions and other values are also showing very less values?

Why is it so? Can anyone explain the reasons ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the values in the Analytics interface are sampled?
Check if there is a green or yellow shield at the top of the Analytics reports (if it's yellow you probably find that the data is based on a percentage of the total data).
This could be the explanation considering that you are selecting a very long period.